# expression translater or parser

Tags: c#, parsing, expression

I need an algorithm that parse an expression and translate into  C# expression.
For example an input string looks like:

**MSG[CORRECTION] AND (NOT TIMERRUN[CYCLE] OR TIME[SHIFT]>120)**

and after translate:

**message.Tag =="CORRECTION" && (!timers["CYCLE"].IsRunning || timers["SHIFT"].value>120)**

Currently I use Regex replace to translate, but I'd like a more elegant and more stable solution. 
I don't want evaluate the expressions, only translate them.
The best solution would be a library.
Thanks.

Comment: A library will take up a lot of memory and take time to look up if you have a lot of different error messages.  So there is a trade off.  To make a library either create create a Dictionary<string,string> or read messages from a file.

Comment: This seems underspecified. What makes `MSG[CORRECTION]` become `message.Tag == "CORRECTION"` but `TIMERRUN[CYCLE]` become `timers["CYCLE"].IsRunning`? `TIME[SHIFT]` becomes something different, too. Unless you're already familiar with a parsing library I doubt using one will help. I'd suggest sticking with regex or learning how to write a parser.

Comment: There are tons of parser frameworks to choose and you just need to google with correct keywords.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2245962/is-there-an-alternative-for-flex-bison-that-is-usable-on-8-bit-embedded-systems/2336769#2336769 for how to write recursive descent parsers for expressions (this is actually relatively easy).   If you follow that thread, it leads to other SO answers that describe how to build and process ASTs; you can probably fit you conversion into that framework.

Comment: If OP doesn't want to hand-code a parser, see this SR answer that discusses a methodical approach to OP's problem: http://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com/a/31379/101